# Create Data Conversion Package C++!

Tags: ros, data, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem with this [tutorial about creating a `header file`](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Create%20Data%20Conversion%20Package%20%28C%2B%2B%29). I do not understand what I should do and how should I do that. Can anyone give a clue? Or some links where I can learn about these header?
In this tutorial we need to have some knowledge, but where are the tutorials that have taught us about those `header file`. Nowhere was the `header file` mentioned (or I missed it).
Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279824/create-data-conversion-package-c++!/) by [xtrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/32780/xtrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-15**:
a `Header file` is a General C++ construct and not (directly) related to ROS.
What is your exact question here?

**Comment by [xtrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/32780/xtrix/) on 2018-01-15**:
The question....
I think there is no one question. Is the expression of a misunderstanding the tutorial. I am a newnewbe so I expected to follow some clear instruction (as it was untill that tutorial). But I got lost whit this 'header file'. I don't know where should I put it,...

**Comment by [xtrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/32780/xtrix/) on 2018-01-15**:
... if it has some standard type, if it belong to 'learning_tf2' package, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial you're attempting is an intermediate level, I would not advise you to start here if you're not familiar with fairly complex C++ projects already.

There is a good [tutorial here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/) that explains why and how c header files are used in projects. If you can have a play around with the examples shown here in a separate (non-ROS) project to get used to working with .c and .h files then this ROS tutorial should make more sense.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xtrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/32780/xtrix/) on 2018-01-15**:
Thanks for your reply. As i said above I got lost but your answer seems answer my misunderstanding